# Open new window on dock middleclick

Tags: applescript, automator, trackpad

I am using a MacBook Pro M1, and have installed MiddleClick.
I am open to an Automator/AppleScript solution, but it's my first day on a Mac, so if you go down this road please explain it step by step.

Right now, middle clicking (three fingers tap) on a dock icon does the same as right clicking (two fingers tap). It brings up a menu, and on relevant app (chrome and terminal, mainly), displays a "New Window" option. I'd like middle clicking to directly open a new window.

I am aware of [How to make clicking on icon in dock == open new instance](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46224/how-to-make-clicking-on-icon-in-dock-open-new-instance) but I don't like this solution as it requires to make one script by app, which I don't want to maintain, and I don't know how to change click to middle click.

Is it possible to make a script that listens to your action, and activate on signal "dock middle click", captures the app you clicked and so on?

If not, I'll settle for the acceptable solution of replacing click by middle click in the aforementioned solution.

Thank you!

Comment: This does seem a lot of effort to go to in order to replace something as simple as Cmd/N for new window or Cmd/T for new tab. I can't see any way to achieve what you want based on a hover over a Dock icon; you're not invoking the app directly that way, just in effect, a shortcut to it.

Comment: cmd/N only works if I already have the desired app in focus

Comment: Correct. At the time you click the dock, that app isn't in focus either - that was my point. tbh, if you're fresh from the world of 'alt/tab' have a look at Spaces to see how you can make your life smarter - https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275